# AzurePipeline failing due to: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, build-server

I have an Azure pipeline setup for my builds. I have been running into this issue recently and cannot figure out a way to fix this:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

About a week or so ago lots of our builds were failing, MS had changed something and we were getting this sort of thing:

```
[error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\codegeneration.roslyn.buildtime\0.6.1\build\CodeGeneration.Roslyn.BuildTime.targets(73,5): Error CGR1001: CodeGeneration.Roslyn.Tool (dotnet-codegen) is not available, code generation won't run. Please check https://github.com/AArnott/CodeGeneration.Roslyn for usage instructions.
```

However was able to solve this by explicitily adding a task to include the netcore2.1 sdk

```yaml
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '2.x'
```

Now this issues is fixed we are now posed with the error complaining it cannot find .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Anyways any idea whats going on, this is driving me banannas - any advice or insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might sound obvious, but did you check that *all* of your build agents supporting 4.6.1? That's a very old version of .NET so it may be as simple as adding that back.

Comment: Thanks @Kit - how do you check that I will look into it?

Comment: In the past I've remoted into and inspected the server(s) or container(s) the agents run on to see if they have the required setup/SDKs. I wish I could be more specific but I'm not using Azure DevOps these days.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**The .Net framework version `4.6.1` has been deprecated by Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted agent.** For now, there are two kinds of Microsoft-hosted agents:

`windows-2019` OR `windows-latest`: .Net framework version `4.7.2` and `4.8` preinstalled. This is documented [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/b410b609eb2117007c3ba135b49fa41211d9f8d1/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-framework).

`windows-2022`: .Net framework version `4.8` preinstalled. This is documented [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md#net-framework).

**That is, you need to use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to use .Net framework `4.6.1` in the pipeline.**

Comment: Whilst this is mostly accurate, you can change the agent specification of a windows hosted agent in the agent pool to run Windows-2019 and this will address the issue. This is documented [here](https://blog.novacare.no/devops-change-agent-specification-to-windows-latest/)

Comment: vmImage: 'windows-2019' in the yml worked with 4.6.1 for me, so no need to use a self-hosted agent.

Comment: vmImage: 'windows-2019' still working for .Net Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 11):

From Agent pool - Change Agent Specification from Window-Latest to Window-2019 ,It seems MS has done some changes in default agent

[image: Pipeline setting]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Specifically, updating the azure-pipelines.yml **pool** configuration section for the Pipeline to `vmImage: 'windows-2019'` from  `vmImage: 'windows-latest'` resolved the issue for me